# Pejorative for a room of low quality (esp. prison cell)

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

I am a non-native speaker looking for a pejorative describing a living space that is of extremely low quality and condition, especially (but not necessarily limited to) a prison cell.

I did some research and found *hole*  and *hovel*, but still wonder if there is something more suitable.

A paraphrase would be fine as well.

> He found himself sitting in this __

Comment: I was about to suggest 'hovel' before you added it. However hovel does not apply to a prison cell - it applies to someone's home. Do you specifically want to describe a cell or do you want to describe an everyday dwelling?

Comment: The word would be used for a prison cell but I'm fine if it can be used for anything else as well

Comment: *Ghetto* might fit, but it doesn't necessarily mean "a prison cell/room".

Comment: @Rathony wouldn't *Ghetto* rather describe an area than a single room or living space?

Comment: Yes. That's why I didn't put it as an answer.

Comment: "extremely low quality and condition" is  vague, hence the range of replies. You must also consider that you are indirectly characterizing either your narrator or your subject when choosing this word. So you need to give not only a little description of the place but a brief description of your protagonist if you're hoping for anything like the *mot juste*.

Comment: A "slum" ? (any squalid, run-down place to live; a very untidy place) *Example: His house is a slum*.

Comment: Poorly decorated?  Poorly appointed?

Comment: You have great answers below, but which one is most appropriate really depends on the context.

Comment: @TimRomano has it right. It would be hard to suggest the right word without knowing more about what specifically the speaker finds objectionable.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A [*shithole*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shithole), as defined by Oxford Dictionaries Online, is slang for a terrible place to live in.

> An extremely dirty, shabby, or otherwise unpleasant place

Comment: Also, it should be pointed out to non-native speakers that this would be viewed by some as highly offensive.

Comment: This sounds pretty much like the thing I'd like to describe, thanks. I'll wait for others before I accept, though

Comment: If you want a slightly less offensive version then 'rat-hole' is another possibility.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I would vote for it.

Comment: A "shithole" is definitely an appropriate (though offensive) word for describing a low-quality location, but I'm not so sure that it's normal to refer to a prison-cell as such. Prisons aren't really expected to be high-quality places to spend time in to begin with. To call a prison cell a "shithole" would seem to suggest that there exist cells that *aren't* low-quality, which is why the usage of the word in that context seems a little odd.

Comment: @Cupcake I disagree. A normal, civilized cell wouldn't be a shithole but merely a very uncomfortable place to be

Comment: There are plenty of prisons that are, for prisons, reasonably comfortable. https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=fancy%20jail%20cells - then there are regular prisons, which suck, and then there are prisons that are shitholes. You can tell that last one, often, by the presence of *literal* feces, which anywhere remotely civilized would be disposed of in the normal fashion, but in a shithole of a prison cell, might end up in a bucket.

Comment: @Cupcake, to me, *shithole* connotes a dingy, uncomfortable place that I really don't want to be in. I don't think it carries any connotation that the place could be or should be nicer. Of course, I can't speak for other English-speakers.

Comment: I find that word simply not acceptable, under any circumstances. My vote is definitely for "dump"

Answer (score 47):

An unpleasant and dreary place can be called a [*dump*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dump).

> **Dump** 
>   *noun* 
>   An unpleasant or dreary place 
>   *Why are you living in a **dump** like this?*

Oxford Dictionaries Online, linked here, has other examples.

Comment: +1 And there is that classic line by Bette Davis in the movie *Beyond the Forest*, disparaging her home: [*What a dump!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3zShjyaTr8)

Comment: Note here that in the literal sense, a "dump" is where garbage is permanently disposed of, as in, "Have that junk taken to the dump."  This is a very strong perjorative, but is much more appropriate in polite company than "shithole" or "hellhole".  After all, no one would want to live anywhere near a dump.

Comment: +1 I think this is the best "neutral" answer addressing the "not necessarily a prison cell" aspect of the question. On the ISO squalor scale, a dump is far better appointed than a shit-hole or a hellhole.

Answer (score 39):

Consider *[hellhole](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hellhole)*

> A place of extreme wretchedness or squalor.

*American Heritage Dictionary*

This is often used to describe actual prisons where the conditions are extreme. Its use, however is not limited to prisons, and often describes other unpleasant locations.

Comment: Agreed, when I hear hellhole, I immediately think of a prison or asylum, not just an unpleasant location.

Comment: To me, "hellhole" implies a place that is actively dangerous or detrimental to your well-being. I didn't get the sense that that was what the OP was after.

Answer (score 16):

[Pigsty](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pigsty) has the following meaning in Merriam-Webster.

> a place where pigs are kept
>
> a dirty or messy place

I cannot think of a dirtier place than where pigs live and it can be a good alternative for the *hole* words suggested above.

Comment: Worms live in pretty dirty holes ...

Comment: @LamarLatrell Depends on what worm you are talking about. Some of them live inside human beings and I don't want to call it dirty holes.

Comment: Well, I'm talking about earthworms ... 'cannot think of a dirtier place' made me think of dirt, then worms, then the fact that worms effectively live in 'holes', and that your post talks about your dirtiest place being a good alternative for hole ... and then ...  ya dig ?

Comment: @LamarLatrell +1 for your thinking process. BTW, *wormhole* doens't have a connotation of a *"dirty" place*.

Comment: And yet, it is nothing *but dirt* - interesting for me at least ...  :)

Comment: @LamarLatrell Have my answer and comments helped?

Comment: um, in what context? I feel like these comments have fallen off the tracks maybe (?) - know that I'm just shooting the breeze, my original comment was just meant to be a little observation, that would hopefully live a short little online life and maybe make one or two people who think the same way smile - maybe I should have included a smiley face?

Comment: It should be noted that the connotation of calling something a pigsty, is that the dirty condition of the place is the fault of those living in it (that those who live there are pigs).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other good ones (hovel, hellhole, dump, etc) squalor is a good one.

*He found himself sitting in this **squalor**.*

To imply a prison cell you don't necessarily have to package that implication into that part of the sentence. One could also write.

*He found himself **imprisoned** in this **squalor/hovel/hellhole/dump**.*

That would then carry the notion that the "squalor" was a cell/prison.

Comment: I always thought squalor would describe a state of neglectedness?

Comment: @Sprottenwels: Indeed. "Squalor" implies neglect, removable dirt or untidiness, and hence a negative judgement on the inhabitants failure to tidy it up. "Dump", on the other hand, suggests the problem lies in the place rather than the people. Of course you could always combine them into "squalid dump".

Comment: @Sprottenwels - Close. I think it's more accurate to say it means some sort of undesirable place like the other words, with the added implication that it is likely that way because of being neglected. To me that's slightly different from actually describing a state neglect itself. I still believe it fits as an option for the OP. Nothing in the OP implied that such connotation would not make an answer eligible. But I recognize that, depending on the author's intentions, it could not be the perfect answer which is why I noted that it's an option in addition to the other good words listed so far.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that "cell" itself works well. You don't have to use it for only prison cells, and the connotation of conditions will still exist (well, assuming the reader knows what prison cells are like). Tiny, spartan and not designed for comfort or amenities (unless you're in Japan or Norway), potentially unclean...

Of course, if you want to give an even stronger impression, you could use something like "dungeon".

Comment: A mere cell, however, wouldn't be of *extremely* low quality and condtion but just uncomfortable.

Comment: That depends where the cell is. A cell in a prison of a western industrialized country is probably entirely different to a cell in Asia or Africa.

Comment: A prison cell isn't the only kind of cell. The tiny, spartan rooms where nuns and monks live are also called *cells* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monastic_cell). In fact, based on the etymology at (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cell), I suspect this usage predates *prison cell*.

Answer (score 2):

pigsty, rat-hole, sewer-pit... so many to choose from!

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

- **slum**: often refers to a street or district but it can also be used to describe a house or building
- **shack**: describes a poorly constructed and often small dwelling which is likely to fall apart
- **pit**: a physically low dirty place (would go along with the idea of a hole)

Comment: Hole in the wall doesn't fit at all - it's often used *positively*. It means a tiny, easily-missed commercial establishment, which are notably often the best kinds, especially if you're talking about Mexican food. It definitely wouldn't ever be used to describe a prison cell.

Comment: Note that "slum" has racial overtones.  I don't think I've ever heard of it being used to describe a specific room, especially a prison cell.

Comment: @RiceFlourCookies I don't know why you think "Slum" has racial overtones.

Answer (score 1):

A prison cell if it is shared feels *cramped*, *stifling* and, often,  *claustrophobic*. The term ***cage*** conveys the image of a person trapped in a small confined space.

> **[cage](https://www.google.it/search?q=cage&oq=cage&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=cage%20definition)**: 1. *a structure of bars or wires in which birds or other animals are confined. 2. a prison cell or camp*.

If the OP wants to express the sheer desolation then I suggest the following

He found himself sitting in his [**godforsaken**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/godforsaken) room/bedsit/cubicle/cell etc.

> (TFD) **godforsaken**
>   1. Located in a dismal or remote area.
>   2. Desolate; forlorn.

Answer (score 1):

squalor (noun)
1. the condition of being squalid; filth and misery.

Synonyms: wretchedness

Example:
Even in the aftermath of the earthquake, the CNN camera crew easily captured the squalor that existed in the facility.

Answer (score 0):

Messy/Tacky/Sloppy room or filthy place

Comment: Thanks so far. Messy would rather indicate untidiness I guess and I always thought tacky would rather be used to describe bad taste. All in all, these are sort of too weak to me

Comment: @Sprottenwels yes, "tacky" is used to describe something that has poor taste, but is not necessarily low-quality. You could have an expensive apartment that is decorated with lots of expensive artwork, but someone mind find the decorations to be "tacky", even if they are of high-quality.