# What did Trump actually mean by the word "****hole"?

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, idiom-requests, offensive-language

- [President Donald Trump referred to African countries, Haiti and El Salvador as "shithole" nations during a meeting Thursday](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/white-house/trump-referred-haiti-african-countries-shithole-nations-n836946)

What did Trump actually mean by the word "shithole"?

In this particular case or in general use, what would be the non-vulgar alternative to the word *shithole*?

Comment: There is none. This is direct quotation and you're not allowed to change that.

Comment: Related: [Pejorative for a room of low quality (esp. prison cell)](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/278681/191178)

Comment: Who said the OP is going to change the quote?  I think he just wants a non-vulgar alternative.  I'd suggest low-standard-of-living countries.

Comment: Are you asking **(1)** what would be the non-vulgar alternative for that term as used in that **particular** context, or **(2)** what would be the non-vulgar alternative for it **generally** (and are referring to this instance of its use merely as an example that is not essential to the core of the question)?

Comment: The question should explain in its text what Trump meant by shit hole, otherwise it's a crappy question (rather ironically).

Comment: Did you look up the word in “the dictionary”? It’s there (even in the *OED*), and there you can find alternatives.

Comment: While I voted to reopen the question in its earlier formulation, the recent edits have turned it into a question that calls for explication and analysis of somebody's political views, rather than a question about a particular English word and possible alternatives to it. These changes definitely put the question outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative that best captures the spirit of the quote would be "hellhole".

"President Donald Trump expressed his belief that African countries, Haiti and El Salvador are hellholes during a meeting Thursday"

The slight tweaking of the quote is necessary in order to not misattribute words to Trump, while still attributing the underlying idea.

Comment: It isn't directly related to English, but one thing to be aware of is that the Trump's vulgarity was a large part of the story. A more tactful politician could likely have noted that safety, economy, and other quality of life variables represent a push factor that makes unlawful immigration to the US more likely, and it would barely make the news. In most circumstances, it would be better to simply render the word as "s***hole", as Trump's vulgar word choice was a significant part of the story.

Comment: Of course, some folks would also consider "hellhole" vulgar. There are still people who insist on referring to "hell" (when used casually, even when not used as an interjection) euphemistically. Typically it's replaced with "heck" or (in America) "H-E-double-hockey-sticks," but neither of those would work in the compound "hellhole" ("heckhole" sounds dreadful).

Comment: While some people may indeed use *hellhole* with roughly the same intentions, it would be misleading to use one of these words (even without quotation marks) when reporting on somebody's having used the other, in the way that is suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

A non-vulgar but still rather insulting approach would be to call such countries **backward.**

[MacMillan defines the word as:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/backward_1)

> not developing quickly, normally, and successfully

[Collins defines it as:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/backward)

> A backward country or society does not have modern industries and machines.

Comment: While I don't know/care what Trump was talking about, a place can be backward and yet charming or picturesque.